# Self Learning Quantum Computing and helpful resources that can aid, guide and teach Quantum Computing from CS&E perspective

Tags: self-learning, resource-request, quantum-computing

> Most technologists have some basic understanding of quantum computing.
> Quantum bits are represented by qubits, and information isn’t simply a
> zero or one, it can be both at the same time, representing much more
> information.  A quantum effect known as entanglement linking two
> particles allows instantaneous communication.
>
> Ultimately, quantum computing promises to be a disruptive technology
> with such dramatic speed improvements that real tractable solutions to
> hard problems could be solved in hours and days. These same problems
> would take hundreds of years to solve on our best supercomputers,
> known as a classical computer, by brute-forcing their way searching
> through all possible solutions.
>
> ...

Reference: Ludlow, Nella. Forbes. [*Why Quantum Computing's Time Is Now*](https://www.forbes.com/sites/cognitiveworld/2019/02/24/why-quantum-computings-time-is-now/?sh=5d56306358d4). Feb 24, 2019. Date Accessed - Dec 27, 2020.

---

Quantum Computing is regarded as one of the most *disruptive technology* as well as *emerging technology*[1,2]. This field has attracted a lot of computational startups and investments in the recent years[3, 4, 5]. With such a pretty new field to learn and work on lacks some material/online courses to self learn Quantum Computing from Computer Science and Engineering perspective. So, the question focuses on the good quality resources to/for:

1. Self-Learning Quantum Computing to build Quantum Computing Simulations on a digital Computer.
2. Development of software, programming of such computer systems.
3. Hardware and Physical implementation from the perspective of CS Engineers.
4. Deployment and Integration (hybrid systems) with Digital Computer.
5. Related areas of disruption of cryptography, internet, data, AI, etc.

*The answers may be answered in the forms of links/resources to - scientific articles, papers, online courses/videos and Books that can aid or teach self learner Quantum Computing.*

---

### Bibliography:

1. Sharma, Vivek. [www.marshall.usc.edu](http://www.marshall.usc.edu). [*What makes Quantum Computing disruptive?*](https://www.marshall.usc.edu/blog/what-makes-quantum-computing-disruptive). Oct 23, 2017. Date Accessed - Dec 27, 2020.
2. The Cipher Brief. [www.thecipherbrief.com](http://www.thecipherbrief.com). [*Why Should I Care about Quantum Computing?*](https://www.thecipherbrief.com/why-should-i-care-about-quantum-computing). Mar 19, 2020. Date Accessed - Dec 27, 2020.
3. Vance, Jeff. Network World. [*10 hot quantum-computing startups to watch*](https://www.networkworld.com/article/3489098/10-hot-quantum-computing-startups-to-watch.html). Feb 15, 2019. Date Accessed - Dec 27, 2020.
4. Bajpai, Prableem. Nasdaq. [*Quantum Computing: How To Invest In It, And Which Companies Are Leading the Way?*](https://www.nasdaq.com/articles/quantum-computing%3A-how-to-invest-in-it-and-which-companies-are-leading-the-way-2020-02-11). Feb 11, 2020. Date Accessed - Dec 27, 2020.
5. Qureca. [*Overview on quantum initiatives worldwide*](https://www.qureca.com/overview-on-quantum-initiatives-worldwide/). Sept 7, 2020. Date Accessed - Dec 27.

Answer (score 3):

The answer written here has been referenced from some of the leading Quantum Computing research Journals or Publications. The interested readers are advised to visit their website in order to get the rough idea of research trend and field segments before self reading Quantum Computing.

The publications/journals include -  *IEEE Quantum*, *Quantum Information Processing* by *Springer*, *Journal of Quantum Computing* By *Tech Science Press*, *Quantum Journal* and *Quantum Computing* by *IOP* [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]. Trends were mainly picked up from Google Scholar, ArXiv Open Access Repos and Online Courses by Reputed Universities.

The interested enthusiast may start from the notes/cheatsheets before moving to books/online course videos.

---

### Methodology

Books were given preference over paper as it can be more helpful for a self learner or anyone needing assistance/help in the field. The main books are solemnly chosen on the basis of higher citations (quality and research impact), whereas reference books on the basis of citations (atleast more than 50 for the given topic) as well as date of publication (newer material given more preference). The order of listing is on the basis of *citations only!*.

The answer includes video material/courses as well as papers/cheatsheets that'd be helpful for a beginner in an *arbitrary order and not in any preference!*

---

### Cheatsheets/Notes

1. [Microsoft Research - Quantum Computing](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/research/uploads/prod/2018/05/40655.compressed.pdf)

### Books

1. **Quantum Computing and Quantum Information :**

   1. *Quantum Computation and Quantum Information* By Michael A. Nielsen & Isaac L. Chuang

*Reference Books:*

1. *Introduction to Quantum Computation and Quantum Information* By Hoi Kwong Lo, Sandu Popescu, Tim Spiller
2. *A First Introduction to Quantum Computing and Information* By Bernard Zygelman
3. **Quantum Networking :**

   1. *Quantum Networking* By Rodney Van Meter

*Reference Books:*

1. *Schrödinger’s Killer App Race to Build the World’s First Quantum Computer* By Jonathan P. Dowling
2. **Quantum Artificial Intelligence:**

   1.*Quantum Machine Learning* By Siddhartha Bhattacharyya, Indrajit Pan, Ashish Mani, Sourav De, Elizabeth Behrman, Susanta Chakraborti (Eds.)

*Reference Books:*

1.*Supervised Learning with Quantum Computers* By Maria Schuld Francesco Petruccione

2.*Quantum Machine Learning What Quantum Computing Means to Data Mining* By Peter Wittek

4. **Quantum Optics:**

   1. *A guide to experiments in Quantum Optics* By Hans A Bachor, Timothy C Ralph
   2. *The Quantum Theory of Light* By Rodney Loudon
5. **Simulations and Hardware:**

   1. *Quantum Optics for Engineers* By F.J. Duarte

   2.*Dancing with Qubits* By Robert S Sutor
6. **Quantum Error Correction and Fault Tolerance :**

   1. *Quantum Error Correction* - DA Lidar, TA Brun
7. **Quantum Entanglement:**

   1.*Geometry of Quantum States: An Introduction to Quantum Entanglement* By Ingemar Bengtsson, Karol Życzkowski

### Important Papers/Resources on Quantum Mechanics

1. A. EINSTEIN, N. ROSEN and B. PODOLSKY, Phys. Rev. 47, 777 (1935). [Can Quantum-Mechanical Description of Physical Reality Be Considered Complete?](https://journals.aps.org/pr/abstract/10.1103/PhysRev.47.777);
2. *Introduction to Quantum Mechanics* By David J. Griffiths
3. [*Spontaneous parametric down-conversion*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spontaneous_parametric_down-conversion)

### Courses/Video Lectures

1. [*Quantum Information and Computing*](https://nptel.ac.in/courses/115/101/115101092/)
2. [Quantum Computing](https://onlinecourses.nptel.ac.in/noc19_cy31/preview)

---

### Bibliography

1. IEEE Quantum. https://quantum.ieee.org/
2. Quantum Information Processing. https://www.springer.com/journal/11128
3. Journal of Quantum Computing. https://www.techscience.com/JQC/index.html
4. Quantum - The open journal for Quantum Science. https://quantum-journal.org/
5. Quantum computing. https://iopscience.iop.org/article/10.1088/0034-4885/61/2/002/meta

Answer (score 1):

Try:

- AWS tutorials https://aws.amazon.com/braket/getting-started/?braket-blogs.sort-by=item.additionalFields.createdDate&braket-blogs.sort-order=desc
- IBM tutorials https://qiskit.org/textbook/preface.html

Explore using:

- Drag gates onto a circuit using Quirk. Click Menu button to access tutorials. [https://algassert.com/quirk#circuit={%22cols%22:[[%22H%22],[%22%E2%80%A2%22,%22X%22]]}](https://algassert.com/quirk#circuit=%7B%22cols%22:%5B%5B%22H%22%5D,%5B%22%E2%80%A2%22,%22X%22%5D%5D%7D)